# Child component data isn't binding/reacting

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've a child component which is the result from a set of search results.

Snippet from the parent template:

```
<result v-for="result in search_results" :item="result" :closeAllServices="closeAllServices"></result>
```

Below is the child(result) template

```
<template>
  <service v-if="isActive" :serviceId="item.id"></service>
</template>

<script>
import showService from './show-service';

export default {
  components: {
    showService
  },
  props: ['item', 'allClosed'],
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: this.allClosed,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Each result can be expanded/collapsed via a button on the result. However, I would like to be able to close all results from the parent template.

When `isActive == true` the results expand, and false collapse. I initiate `isActive` via a prop `closeAllServices` which is set to `false`.

I have a button, which when clicked sets `closeAllServices = true`

I can see (via the Vue Panel in Chrome) that the prop `closeAllServices` is being changed when the button is being clicked, but `isActive` doesn't change.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Did you mean to do `:all-closed="closeAllServices"'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only initializing `isActive` in data. That means it will not change when the property changes.

```
data() {
  return {
    // This only ever executes when the component is created
    isActive: this.allClosed,
  }
}
```

With all that you have shown, I would probably just reference `allClosed` directly in the template.

```
<service v-if="allClosed" :serviceId="item.id"></service>
```

If there is some other logic that goes into whether `isActive` is true or false you might want to use a computed.

```
computed:{
  isActive(){
     return this.allClosed //plus whatever other logic to determine isActive
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought this was the case, I was just sure I had solved it before. I think I will have to use a computed property. Thanks